# Google static map just showing the img icon

Tags: html, visual-studio, google-maps

So im trying to load a static google map img, but there is only the image icon showing. This is a given code from and examination so i can't find what seems to be the problem.

Here is the result:

[image]

And below is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Google Map karta LTU</title>
</head>
<body>
    <img src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=65.61835,22.140&zoom=14&size=512x512&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:blue%7Clabel:L%7C65.61835,22.140&key=AIzaSyC7p1EldP9HoI1ziysd2BZ9vvqSNNt35Dk"
    alt="Google Map"
    style="width:505px" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is what the Google Maps API is telling you, based on the information you have: `The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The provided API key is invalid.`

Answer (score 0):

If you visit the site, you can see that the problem is written there:

> The Google Maps API server rejected your request. This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/static_maps_backend?project=_

Activate your API and provide the key necessary for displaying static images.

Comment: that's because you can't use my API @the4kman
look at the img i linked

Comment: What do you get when you display the link's content in an `iframe`?

Comment: i only get an all blank iframe